# Inject custom object via ConstructorArgument in dependant objects

Tags: c#, ninject

I want to inject my user object into my Principal object like so:

```
kernel.Get<IPrincipal>(new ConstructorArgument("user", user));
```

This is the concrete implementation of IPrincipal constructor

```
public Principal(User user, IUserPermissions userPermissions)
{
    /* user is the correct instance, that I passed via ConstructorArgument */
}
```

Up until till here I have no issues. the user object gets passed in fine.

**But** the IUserPermissions is not receiving this very object. Instead ninject creates a new instance of User. Here the concrete implementation of IUserPermissions constructor:

```
public UserPermissions(User user, IDomainRoleValidator domainRoleValidator)
{
    /* user is a fresh instance, **not** the one I passed via ConstructorArgument */
}
```

How can I get this to work without having to add a new Method like 'SetUser'?

Answer (score 0):

You need to scope your bindings.

At present, you have a default binding which is `InTransientScope`.. that is, it will give you a new instance each time it is requested.

You need to scope it another way.. perhaps one per request (for web):

```
using Ninject.Web.Common;

Bind<IPrincipal>().To<ConcreteInstanceHere>().InRequestScope();
```

Or in thread scope:

```
Bind<IPrincipal>().To<ConcreteInstanceHere>().InThreadScope();
```

These will give you the same instance, for their respective scopes.

Comment: InRequestScope has been removed (I assume for a reason). And InThreadScope doesn't apply here.

Comment: `InRequestScope` is part of `Ninject.Web.Common.dll`. Not part of `Ninject.dll`. Either way, the answer is the same. Your scoping is incorrect. The default scope is `InTransientScope`.. which is a new instance each call to `kernel.Get<T>`.

Comment: I'd actually prefer to do it without scope. Unless I can just define a scope for that very Get call...

Comment: "Without scope" is what you have. No scope. To give it a scope, is to give it a reason to serve up the same instance within that scope. Why would you want a new instance every single call? That's madness.. especially if this is a web app. You're creating brand new objects every single time instead of sharing them around for the life of the request...

Comment: the point is, that the parent object is already 'scoped' so there is no need to scope the child as well. What if I want to inject a different user somewhere in this request into a different object?

Comment: Then you can use contextual binding. Would you like an example of that? Are you likely to inject a different user within the same request?

Comment: I've read https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding but unsure of how it applies. So an example, how it could solve my problem would be very welcome!